# Run initialization script on last pod of StatefulSet after liveness probe only once

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have StatefulSet that has 3 replicas. What I am trying to do is to initialize the app that run on them but it needs to be done only once (for the life of the set) and preferable on the last pod (or I will have to wait until the last pod is ready). Let's say this is what it looks like. Any ideas?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  serviceName: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: image/image-test:1.2.3
        livenessProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          tcpSocket:
            port: 12345
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          tcpSocket:
            port: 12345
          timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Comment: Plain Kubernetes on its own doesn't have any notion of waiting for one object to be fully provisioned and then taking an action.  How are you actually deploying this?  If you're using Helm, for example, a post-install [hook](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) might meet your needs.